# Lightswitch: modify behaviour of DataGrid search box

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch

Is it possible to override the behaviour of the search box of the DataGrid.

For example if the user types "tag:Premium" I'd like to get all user that has the tag Premium. Can I manipulate the query somehow? How can I get the search term and cancel out the default query.

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from disabling the default search box, and implementing a custom search box? (Apart from the default behaviour)

Comment: No except that isn't as pretty :)